# How to add text to buttons in table layout and retrieve that text in android developement of tictactoe

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a been developing android app where i have tablelayout and buttons inside that tablerow and i wanted to put some text on that button as i click and later at end of time to retrieve what data i have put.

It is basically tic tac toe game Somebody pls help me with. This is my first android app.
I have previously done tic tac toe programming in basic java code, just trying on android app.

`

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recoomend implementing OnClick listener to the activity,

then in xml you put onclick as an attributes.

When button clicked, you can get the button id.

here an example:

```
YourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    Button b = (Button) v;
    // Your Code
    b.setText();

}
```

then, in xml add this line to buttons

android:onClick="onClick"

Comment: Thanks that worked fine and will be able to move forward atleast.

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate:

```
Button NAME = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);

    NAME.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        //On click function
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NAME.setText(“SOMETHING”);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In java code on every trigger of onClick event set the desired text you want using,

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setText("text");
```

And later retrieve that text using,

```
String text = b.getText();
```